# Loopback: Remote Method is converting "null" to null value

Tags: type-conversion, loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback

I am having an issue where whenever my front end (angular) makes a remote method call that has a string "null" in it once it gets to the remote method in Loopback, Loopback has converted the string "null" to a null value.

For example if a remote method /query takes in a filter:

```
{
    "name": "null"
}
```

Loopback changes it to

```
{
    "name": null
}
```

How could I go about fixing this issue? Note, I do not want to add a convertToString functionality on Loopbacks end. I much rather know what is going on in the backend of Loopback that is causing this and turn off whatever is causing this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's a similar issue here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1819 But that looks like the opposite of what you're experiencing. 

Maybe try adding some remote hooks and checking the ctx to narrow down where the issue is happening? 

Also, assuming you are using loopback 3?

Comment: Thank, Ill check it out and using v 2.34.1

Comment: Do you have the property type set to "string"?

Comment: @JackVaughan yes I do

Comment: What database connector are you using?